# jQuery DataTables Api

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am accessing the data of a jquery data table using table.rows().data(), which is then used in a custom export functionality, is there a way I can access the filtered data, for example if the user performs a search and the records are filtered.

I have looked at the draw event which fires each time the table is redrawn, but the data remains the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an _ function in datatables (since 1.9) which allows you to select all data according to certain specifications. One being "filter":"applied"

`table._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});`

Hopefully that helps...